# EPI-Server 7 PropertyFor doesn't give me any intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver-7

I'm learning EpiServer 7 built on MVC and am now trying to make the PropertyFor work as I want it. I have a property called title and if I write it like this (code below),  it renders correctly but I dont't get any intellisense for the Linq expression inside (the x). You see what namespaces I am using and I have also added System.Linq in the webconfig for views. What do I need to do to get intellisense?

```
@using System
@using System.Data
@using EPiServer.Cms
@using EPiServer.Core
@using EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html

@model MyApplication.Models.Pages.StartPage

<h2 class="@Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Title)">
    @Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Title)
</h2>
```

Note. The alloy MVC demo site have this problem for me as well so can't find any good solution there. I can't add System.Linq in the razor page, the page can't find the reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem. Reinstall EpiServer Command Center, that fixed it for me.

Comment: A little inactive but since you made an answer I thought I could do mine to. Better late then never!

Answer (score 1):

A litle inactive thread but! We have one comment above that solved it in his way. For me I changed the target framework from 4.5 to 4.0 to 4.5. Voila!